# "Type Error: range() integer end argument expected, got float" even using int()

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here is the complete code. What's confusing me is that I'm using int to turn the ceiling of l/2 into an integer and it's still not working. The error would have to be elsewhere in the code unless... well I dun goofd. Thanks

```
def switcheroo(vec):
    from math import ceil
    from __future__ import division
    l = len(vec) - 1
    holdingcell = []
    for i in range(int(ceil(l/2))):
        holdingcell = vec[i]
        vec[i] = vec[l-i+1]
        vec[l-i+1] = holdingcell
    return vec
```

The error I am getting is:

```
>>> o = switcheroo(v)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "switcheroo.py", line 8, in switcheroo
for i in range(int(ceil(l/2))):
TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got float.
```

Comment: Please show the complete error message.

Comment: May you show us a more complete code? l declaration and possible values and complete loop

Comment: The code you provided is correct: the `int` function **does** convert your floating point number in an integer. The error is somewhere else in your code.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli:  Good point!  From what I can see, this code looks ok.

Comment: I've edited this to show the whole code.

Comment: Actually I just tried checking and `int(sys.maxint+1)` does return a valid value to use in a `range`...

Comment: @RockyRaccoon can you tell us exactly which version of Python are you running?

Comment: Sorry, I'm running 2.7.10. I thought I put that in the tags, perhaps I forgot.

For what it's worth I'm testing this on lists that have 4-5 entries so l shouldn't fall out of any maximum range.

Furthermore when i run a line at a time in the console, everything works well and even running range on the exact same code returns a valid range.

Comment: For what it's worth, there are two errors in your code: first, the `from __future __ import division` line should be at the beginning of the file, and not inside your function; second, your `vec[l-i+1]` is out of range. By the way the rest of the code works just fine, and your `range` does not give any error when processing the code. Either you redefined `int()` to do something else or something... otherwise I have no clue about this.